# 'Event' object has no attribute 'e3'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

- **Hi I am new to python and I have been trying to build a simple calculator where there are three boxes, the first box has a
  predefined number.**
- **The second box is user input and the third box is where the product of the first two numbers must appear.**
- **However I am an error 'Event' object has no attribute 'e3'**

Please help

```
    from tkinter import *

    class Calculator(Frame):
        def Widgets(self):
            self.e1 = Entry(self)
            self.e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
            self.e1.insert(0,1)

            self.e3 = Entry(self)
            self.e3.grid(row=1, column=3)

            def estimation_value_1(self):
                self.e3.insert(0, ((e1.get())*(e2.get())))

            self.e2 = Entry(self)
            self.e2.grid(row=1, column=2)
            self.e2.bind("<Return>", estimation_value_1)

        def __init__(self,initial):
            super(Calculator,self).__init__(initial)
            self.grid()
            self.Widgets()

    Window = Tk()
    Window.title("Error")
    Window.geometry("500x500")
    Evaluation_Tool = Calculator(Window)
    Window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Which line does it tell you the error is on?

Comment: line 13  File "C:\Users\Siva\Desktop\Test_2.py", line 13, in estimation_value_1
    self.e3.insert(0, ((e1.get())*(e2.get())))
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'e3'

Comment: Is that the exact code format? because that function inside the method makes no sense... please make sure the indentation and format is correct

Comment: @Incognos: Yeah, the code format is correct. I have found the solution with help of shaowen yin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you it now works as Yin suggested. however, with a small correction. Just converting e1.get and e2.get to float makes it work

```
def estimation_value_1(event):
            self.e3.insert(0, ((float(self.e1.get()))*(float(self.e2.get()))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def estimation_value_1(self):
    self.e3.insert(0, ((e1.get())*(e2.get())))
```

the first parameter of the callback function `estimation_value_1` is the KeyPress Event. In your function, self is the KeyPress event, not the Calculator object.

You can implement in this way:

```
def estimation_value_1(event):
    self.e3.insert(0, ((self.e1.get())*(self.e2.get())))
```